# how to compute image size from width and height pixels to bytes

Tags: image, pixel, image-size

[image property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2X8J.jpg)
 I try to compute image size in byte depend on that equation 
    width * height * bit depth  / 8 
 depend on the [image property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2X8J.jpg) 
    697 * 923 *24  = 15439944 /8  = 1929993  byte
  but the size in byte not identical to the size in property ???

Comment: Its not Width, but Stride.

Comment: so what the solution ??

Comment: Note that [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), which is what you're using here, doesn't actually store the value of every pixel.

Comment: I am on cell phone. So, I can't post source code. But, you can try bitmap locking to read stride size and then try the same calculation.